# Ruby programming - unable to initialize instance variable with default values

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

In the code below, I have given a default value for the accountNumber for when it is not called with a particular value but that value is not recognized by the code, why is that?

```
class BankAccount
   CONST=0100

   def interest_rate
        @@interest_rate = 0.2
   end

   def accountNumber
        @accountNumber
   end

   def accountNumber=(value = 10)
        puts value
        @accountNumber = value
   end
end
```

When I call the accountNumber= method as below with no arg, I expect it to puts "10" but it is not putting out the default value...

```
account1 = BankAccount.new()
puts account1.accountNumber=()
```

Comment: if it's not doing what you expect, what *is* it doing?

Comment: It is a good question, and I thought of doing +1, but the way it is asked is not reader friendly, so I did -1. Remove all the irrelevant things from your code, and I will do +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot be fully sure, but it seems to be some irregularity due to the method name ending with `=`. That type  of methods do not seem to accept default values correctly. When you change the method name to `set_account_number`, then it will work.

Comment: Thanks yes, this certainly seems to be the case, when I remove the "=" from the method name it works fine...

Answer (score 5):

```
account1.accountNumber=(10)
```

Is the same as

```
account1.accountNumber = 10
```

It's weird to use `account1.accountNumber =` without passing value.

If you need default value set it inside constructor.

```
def initialize
  @accountNumber = 10
end
```

then

```
account1 = BankAccount.new
puts account1.accountNumber # => 10
```

Answer (score 4):

ck3g's answer is on point. Just set up your defaults in your initializer. What that in mind, you could simplify your class to just

```
class BankAccount
   CONST=0100
   attr_accessor :accountNumber

   def initialize(accountNumber = 10)
     @accountNumber = accountNumber
   end

   def interest_rate
     @@interest_rate = 0.2
   end
end
```

This lets ruby handle the getter and setter for your accountNumber attribute automatically.

Comment: Thanks ck3g, and jboursiquot...initalizing with the default value and calling a setter optionally with a particular value as you suggest ,works...

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning an empty expression `()` to the setter method. In Ruby, empty expressions evaluate to `nil` (what else would they evaluate to anyway?), therefore you are assigning `nil`.